# textswitcher toast the previous text

Tags: java, android

I have implemented two textswitcher in my app, one is for word and second is for meaning. But the problem is, when I try to save the word and meaning on sharedpreference in the last word, it saves the previous word and meaning is correct .

> Note : For testing purpose I have put 2 words only

Like I have 2 words : A ,B and meaning is M,N;
it saves A = M , A=N;

I am saving the word from the textview :

```
 private TextSwitcher Word,Answer;
     private int String_Index=0;
        private String [] word = {"Der Anzug","Der Apfelstrudel"};
        private int String_Indexa=0;
        private String [] answer = {"Suit","Apple Cake"};
        private TextView w ,a;



    Again_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Answer_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (String_Index == word.length-1){
                    String_Index = 0;
                    Word.setText(word [String_Index]);
                }else {
                    Word.setText(word[++String_Index]);
                }


                if (String_Indexa == answer.length-1){
                    String_Indexa = 0;
                    Answer.setText(answer [String_Indexa]);
                }else {
                    Answer.setText(answer[++String_Indexa]);
                }

                insertItem2(w.getText().toString(), a.getText().toString());
                saveData2();



            }
        });

     private void insertItem2(String line1, String line2) {
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(line1, line2));

    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the implementation of `insertItem2` please. Also, have you verified that the text in `w` and `a` si what you expect?

Comment: check now please.